# tcpdump to filter tcp traffic into csv file

Tags: networking, tcp, filter, tcpdump, system-administration

Can somebody tells me how to use tcpdump to filter out udp or tcp traffic on a specific source and destination ip and save the output into a csv file? 
Its not necessary a csv file if I can convert the pcap file into a csv by using an etl tool.

Also I am interested in a 100ms time resolution when I collect the data, can I do it with tcpdump?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt you could ask **tcpdump** to write in a CSV file, this tool is too simple.

But you could ask **tshark**(it's a console utility from the wireshark package) to do it.

see https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/2935/creating-a-csv-file-with-tshark

Answer (score 6):

You could use the method explained in [this link](https://gnu-linux.org/extract-the-packets-from-pcap-file-to-csv.html) which explains a method with tshark.

> **# tshark -r traffic.pcap -T fields -e ip.src -E separator=, -E occurrence=f > traffic.csv**
> -r: *to read the .pcap file.*
> -T fields: *different fields which are needed to capture.*
> -E separator: *if there are multiple fields extracting separator is used to differentiate.*
> -E occurrence: *Which occurrence is used for the field which has multiple occurrence, ‘f’ is for first and it store the fields inside the .csv file.*
>
> Multiple fields
> **# tshark -r traffic.pcap -T fields -e ip.src -e frame.len -e ip.proto -E separatorr=, -E occurrence=f > traffic.csv**